# How to use async library in a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-services

I'm trying to use the async lib in my service. Eventually I plan to do a series of $resource.query() calls and pass the results down the ladder.

The issue I'm running into is getting my console.log() to wait for the async series to finish.  How do I set up my async_service.async_func() call to make it asynchronous so it waits for all my controller functions to finish before it runs?

```
  angular.module('app.services').factory('async_service', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {

 async_func:function(){

                return async.series([
                    function(callback){
                        //will do  a $resource.query() call eventually
                        callback(null, 'one');
                    },
                    function(callback){
                        //will do  a $resource.query() call eventually
                        callback(null, 'two');
                    }
                ],
                // optional callback
                return function(err, results){
                    return results;
                });
        }
}]);


angular.module('app.controllers', []) .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','async_service', function($scope, async_service) {

    var v = async_service.async_func();
    console.log(v);  //should be ['one', 'two'] but getting undefined

}]);
```

Comment: I don't understand your code at all... but one very good possible solution to your question is to use the $q service in Angular and start using promises. Read up on $q and the $q.all() function. That will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to use `$q` it is angular's promise system. There is no need for the extra bloat of another third party dependency if you use it.

You service would simply be:

```
angular.module('app.services').factory('async_service', ['$resource', '$q',
    function($resource, $q) {
        return {
            async_func: function() {

                return $q.all(['one','two', this.hitApi()]);
            },
            hitApi: function () {
                /*
                    Simulate api call, 
                    $timeout returns a promise which is resolved when the timeout is met.
                    Same as $http
                */
                return $timeout(function(){ return 'three'}, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

And use it as

```
async_service.async_func().then(function (v) {
    /*
        .then() here will be called once all values/promises passed to $q.all have been resolved.
        If it receieves a promise it will wait untill those promises have been resolved.
        This would make it even easier if yo wish to do network calls as they return promises.
    */
    console.log(v);  //Will be ['one', 'two'] 
});
```

There is one caveat to understand. `$q.all` will not execute functions. It merely wraps values in a promise. If that value happens to already be a promise it will wait for it to resolve before resolving itself. That is why i added the `hitApi()` method so you can see how you could accomplish that behavior instead. Also note how the `.then()` in the controller waits for the timeout to finish before firing.

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rjLshbz5/1/
see docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

---

EDIT: Also you initial service wouldn't have run anyhow it would have thrown a syntax error.

This would have been your offending bit (minus the missing `return {}` part of your service but i guess that was an error copying code into SO):

```
            // optional callback
            return function(err, results){
                return results;
            });
```

JavaScript doesn't work like that. You cannot use the `return` keyword in that context. You passing variables into a method, `async.series`, the first being an array the second a callback to complete once you call the done callback in each array function.

`async.series` doesn't return a value. I can't as its execution of the array methods is async.

Answer (score 0):

your console.log printout need to wait until all the calls in the async.series are done. Change your function call to get a callback, and print the return value when it's done:

```
async_func:function(cb) {

            return async.series([
                function(callback){
                    //will do  a $resource.query() call eventually
                    callback(null, 'one');
                },
                function(callback){
                    //will do  a $resource.query() call eventually
                    callback(null, 'two');
                }
            ],
            // optional callback
            function(err, results){
                return cb(err, results);
            });
    }
}]);

async_service.async_func(function(err, results) {
   if (!err)
       console.log(results);
})
```